# How to close the opened file?

Tags: excel, csv

I opened a csv file and copy the contents.
I activated an excel file and have the copied contents from csv file pasted into excel file.
Now, how do I close the csv file programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it ..

```
Workbooks("MYCSV_File.CSV").Close SaveChanges:=False
```